# How can a Wi-Fi access point be visible from one device but not from another?

Tags: wireless-communication

We have a strange issue while trying to configure small router for bridging between available access point and ethernet network. While this AP is perfectly visible from desktops and mobile devices, it is not visible form the bridging router.

I wonder how can it be? Visible WiFI it is just radio signal. Are there any advertised properties which can be filtered on?

Comment: Can you please share the model and make of the AP and router?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the post here are few things to look for and some publicly available open source tools.

First you might want to check the operating frequency, 2.4 GHz, 5GHz or both.

When you are setting up a wireless network it is important to know surrounding in your case for the bridge router. There are many obstacles that can attenuate the wireless signal. Some of these are furniture, walls, metal objects etc.

I use wireshark as my wifi analyzer. Tool is a can be overwhelming. This tool is mostly text based. Below is image of the tool

[image]

Another tool to take a look at is wifi analyzer.

[image]

There are wifi analyzers for both iOS and Android. You might want do some research and find one that fits your needs.

Take a look at these and let us know if these were helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed we have figured out that target WiFi network was available only in 5GHz and one of bridging devices was only 2.4 capable. But still, the second device is 5GHz capable and still does not see the network. Investigating further ...

Comment: @AndreySedelnikov, you are most welcome, if you would please accept the answer, so there is closure to the issue. Also please feel free to come back ask engineering questions or contribute to community by answering questions.